# How to scroll in both directions horizontally and vertically at the same time in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to scroll in both directions horizontally and vertically at the same time in react native app, where i have scrollview contains group of horizontal flatlists.
However I need to stop scrolling horizontally in order to be able to scroll vertically.

```
<ScrollView>
<ItemComponent dataState={this.state.Homepage} renderItemProp={renderItem}/>
<ItemComponent dataState={this.state.Politik}  renderItemProp={renderItem} />
......
....
</ScrollView>
```

ItemComponent :

```
<View >
  <FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  style={{ marginTop:10,marginLeft:15,marginBottom:10 }}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={dataState}
  renderItem={renderItemProp}
             />
</View>
```

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically or is this multi touch ?

Comment: I program it and it works fine, but when the user is scrolling the flatlist horizontally, if he scrolls vertically to the next flatlist under it, he needs to wait until the previous flatlist stops scrolling horizontally then he can do it.